# Apple Mach-O Linker Error, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios8, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1

i just started iOS programming and am trying to compile a simple code but am unable to do so. The error messages i received are,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Player", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now, i have found 2 similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552855/xcode-6-1-missing-required-architecture-x86-64-in-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1)) that are using the same environment as i am to code and are facing similar issues as i am too. I have tried their solutions but am unsuccessful.

As i just started iOS, i was using this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) as a guide and am trying to run their code. The error occurs at the part where i assign some value to the player variable. Code are as follows.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayersViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate{
    NSMutableArray *_players;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary        *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    _players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

    Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
    player.name = @"Bill Evans"; //error will occur here

    return YES;
}
```

My Architecture settings are as follows,
[image: ArchitectureSettings]

The code for the Player.h and PlayersViewController.h are exactly the same with those from the tutorial.

**Update**

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *game;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating;

@end
```

PlayersViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayersViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *players;

@end
```

My build results
[image: BuildResults]

Comment: Sounds like you haven't added the source file containing the `Player` class to the Xcode target.  Check the build logs and see if it's being compiled.

Comment: Does that mean a .m file for Player needs to be included as well ? I followed the tutorial and all they mentioned were the .h files. I will update my question with the contents of the .h files.

Comment: So, as embarrassing as it is, it really does seem i need to include a .m file and specify the '@sysnthesize' syntax for those variables that i declared with the '@property' syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Player.h file, i had to include the .m file for it too.
The code for the .m file are as follows,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize game = _game;

@end
```

It manages to build but there are errors when running. However, that is for another question.