# iOS Speech Recognizer of OpenEars results in Apple Mach-O Linker Errors: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, openears

I tried to implement [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#OELanguageModelGenerator_Class_Reference) Speech Recognizer. Since the downloaded tutorial compiles without any problems, when I tried to write my own simple **objective-C** code following the [tutorial](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial), I got five Apple Mach-O Linker Errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OEAcousticModel", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OELanguageModelGenerator", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OEPocketsphinxController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to reopen XCode, added some libraries/frameworks (like CoreData), checked the target memberships, but still get the same errors. I tried the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device) but they did not help. By the way adding `SenTestingKit.framework` decreased the number of errors from five to one. But still I am stucked with linker type errors. These issues are related to the linking, not coding itself as far as I know.

Some details: running iOS SDK 8.4, XCode 6.4 (6E35b) version. Added libraries like: `CoreData.framework`, `AVFoundation.framework`, `AudioToolbox.framework` and Frameworks of OpenEars (`OpenEars.framework`, `Sit.framework`).

p. s. Between, I need a decent speech recognizer for iOS and OS X using objective-C, not necessarily OpenEars, so, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: cannot see any reason to downvote instead of suggesting any solution.

Answer (score 1):

There were a weird reason. Following the instructions I copied OpenEars' Framework folder into XCode project, and chose "Create folder references" as well as "Copy items if needed", but choosing another option "Create groups" solved the issues. Between, I see that "Framework" folder with the content appeared in project folder as well.

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't trivial for me, since I'm using cordova and it created automatically a reference