# XMLDictionaryParser Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting Linked error after adding XMLDictionaryParser files, I see in some of the statckoverflow questions they have suggested to remove x86_64 from valid architecture, but removing that cause many other linker errors for me.I have added both .h and .m files for XMLDictionaryParser from github- https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary  -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLDictionaryParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: There are two main possibilities: 1) you are not linking-in the framework/library containing that class. 2) the framework/library was not compiled for `x86_64` CPU architecture.  To solve: 1) check the linker command line. 2) Use `file` on the framework/library and see what CPUs it supports.  There is nothing more we can do.

Comment: Please check this url solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1

Comment: Please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1