# Cordova - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am running `cordova build ios` with Cordova and receiving this error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ESUserInfoResponse", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_ESUserInfoResponse_$_TMConvenience in TicketmasterSDK(ESUserInfoResponse+TMConvenience.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ESConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TicketmasterSDK(TMExperienceController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ESProductInfoResponse", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_ESProductInfoResponse_$_Convenience in TicketmasterSDK(ESProductInfoResponse+Convenience.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ExperienceSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TicketmasterSDK(TMExperienceController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ESUserInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TicketmasterSDK(TMExperienceController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have followed this question: [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Xcode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1/26561570#26561570)
The main .h and .m are generated by Cordova and I am using Swift for a custom plugin.

It builds and runs when opening the Xcode workspace and running in Simulator, but it errors when compiling through Cordova. How can I fix this and how can I find out how Cordova builds natively for iOS?

Comment: Did you get it resolved? I'm facing the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your files might be missing from the project. If you added custom code to AppDelegate.m file then open the project in xCode, Click on the first tab called Navigator, Rt click on the Classes folder and then select "Add files to [project]". Add the missing files that you were referencing in there and hit Build. It should work now. It worked for me!