# I am getting this weird error when instantiating Objective C Controller from Swift Code

Tags: objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

I have added a group of Objective C classes and one storyboard in the existing swift base project. I also added bridging header file but when I instantiate one of the objective c class from the swift code I am facing this error. I have seen many answers and questions but none of them could solve my problem.

i also checked .m file according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1) and everyrhing is perfact there. I added @implementation under the interface.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ContactViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ContactVC.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

here is my swift code.

```
  let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Contacts", bundle: nil)
   let contactsViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactViewController") as? ContactViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(contactsViewController!,
                                             animated: true)
```

Comment: you should import `ContactViewController.h` in the bridging header file so that swift can find it.

Comment: I also importing in the bridging header file.